# insert multiple values with one submit using foreach

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

I am trying to insert multiple values into my table using `foreach` but I can't get it right

this is the HTML CODE

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" id="studentresult">
            <div class="tableDiv_01 table-responsive">
                <div class="tablehHeader">
                    <span class="field col-xs-9">اسم الطلاب</span>
                    <span class="field col-xs-3 text-center">الدرجة</span>
                </div>

                <ul>
                    <?php
                    $active = 1;
                    $getStud = $db->prepare('SELECT
                    a.id, a.std_id, a.subDegree,
                    b.id, b.name
                    FROM student_subjects AS a
                    INNER JOIN student_basic_info AS b ON (a.std_id = b.id)
                    WHERE a.sub_id=? AND a.activitySub=?
                    ');
                    $getStud->bind_param('ii', $sbj, $active);
                    if ($getStud->execute()) {
                        $getStudRes = $getStud->get_result();
                        while ($s = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getStudRes)) {
                            ?>
                            <li>
                                <div class="col-xs-9">
                                    <label for="dg"><?php print $s['name'] ?></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
                                    <input type="text" name="dg" id="dg"
                                           class="specialTextbox form-control1 input-sm">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="stId[]" value="<?php print $s['std_id'] ?>">
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>

                <div class="col-xs-3 pull-left">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="تعديل الدرجات"
                           class="btn-success btn width100per">
                </div>
        </form>
```

this is PHP for the update

```
if (isset($_GET['sbj'])) {
        $sbj = $_GET['sbj'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


        foreach ($_POST['stId'] as $key => $value) {
            $dg = $_POST['dg'][$key];
            $stId = $_POST['stId'][$key];
            echo "$key=$value"."<br/>";
            $update = $db->prepare('UPDATE student_subjects SET subDegree=? WHERE std_id=?');
            $update->bind_param('ii', $sbj, $stId);
            if ($update->execute()) {
                header('Location:?c=10&stdSys=9&sudRes=3&sbj=' . $sbj);
            } else {
                printf("Error : %s\n", $db->error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `form` start and end?

Comment: it's starting from line 1 and ends in the last line!

Comment: Where is your insert query?

Comment: Your <form> is missing, and that might not include ?sbj= parameter which you are using in sql update. Please post whole examples from both the form and the php code handling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put the array sign "[]" in the "dg" input name attribute. please make correction in your script as below and check it now it should be work.

```
<input type="text" name="dg[]" id="dg" class="specialTextbox form-control1 input-sm">
<input type="hidden" name="stId[]" value="<?php print $s['std_id'] ?>">

foreach ($_POST['stId'] as $key => $value) {
    $dg = $_POST['dg'][$key];
    $stId = $_POST['stId'][$key];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes this worked fine but can I put the header under it or not and if not how it should be

Comment: Always welcome dear!, i feel glad to assist you anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would see is that you should give ids to the inputs so that they won't override each other :

```
<input type="hidden" name="stId[<?= $s['std_id'] ?>]" value="<?= $s['std_id'] ?>">
```

Second thing is that if you perform a header location in your foreach loop, it will never be completed

```
foreach ($_POST['stId'] as $key => $value) {
    ...
    // don't do header location here if you want the loop to be completed
}

// then you can redirect
header('Location:?c=10&stdSys=9&sudRes=3&sbj=' . $sbj);
```

third thing is that you should edit your dg input, beacause you are trying to manipulate it as an array but you don't define it as an array

do

```
<input type="text" name="dg" id="dg[<?= $s['std_id'] ?>" class="specialTextbox form-control1 input-sm">
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" name="dg" id="dg" class="specialTextbox form-control1 input-sm">
```

You don't give us enough clues to solve your problem as you don't give any error or explain why you think it doesn't work, where you are stucked etc..

Comment: OK now I am getting `Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 5`

Comment: I edited my answer, you are trying to manipulate an array you did'nt created

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving execution after the first row insert when you reach `header`